# (MSM) - Products not adding to cart

Tags: expresso-store, multi-site-manager

I am using MSM, i have two subdomains with expresso store.

If i add an item to a cart on (sub1.domain.com) and then go to (sub2.domain.com) and try to add an item to the cart it gives {no_items}.

If i empty the cart on (sub1.domain.com) the products Will appear in the (sub2.domain.com) cart that i added previously and vise vera.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Store is MSM compatible but currently carts and products are restricted to the site that they are created in.

If you Store tags make sure that you are setting the `site_id="X"` to the proper site.